# ¿como hago que mi caja se extienda de forma horizontal?

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente código de HTML que crea una caja con un producto "principal" para una tienda online

```css
.C_tarjetahorizontal{
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: contain;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all 400ms ease-out;
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="C_tarjetahorizontal">
    <div class="card">
        </div>
        <figure>
            <img src="https://media.game.es/COVERV2/3D_L/172/172596.png" width="100%" alt="teclado">
            <div class="contenido">
                <span>
                    Producto <br>
                    Review del Producto
                    <br>
                </span>
                <a href="#"> comprar</a>
            </div>
        </figure>
</div>
```

No se si es por la imagen o algo que acomode mal, pero quiero que el texto se coloque del lado derecho y la imagen a la izquierda

Comment: 1 - Tu css aplica a `.C_tarjetahorizontal`, debería ser a `.card`. 2 - la etiqueta `figure` debe estar dentro de `.card` y `.contenido` debe estar fuera de `figure`.

Comment: ¿Bastaría con `.contenido { text-align: end; }` (?...

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr posicionar los elementos como quieres debes aplicar un par de estilos en tu caso a la etiqueta `figure` (no me centrare en la semántica html que tienes puesto a que ese no es el tema principal de tu pregunta), ahora en los estilos de `figure` debes añadir la propiedad `display:inline-flex` de esa manera los elementos se distribuirán horizontalmente de izquierda derecha en base al orden estructural de tu html,
otra alternativa al `display:inline-flex` es usar `display:flex` o algun otro valor con comportamiento similar aplicado en la propiedad `display` pero tu caso no la requiere, te dejo un snippet usando `display:inline-flex` y de igual manera te dejo una referencia de la propiedad `display` para que te documentes https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/display

```css
.C_tarjetahorizontal{
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: contain;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all 400ms ease-out;
    cursor: default;
}
figure{
  display:inline-flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  gap:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="C_tarjetahorizontal">
    <div class="card">
        </div>
        <figure>
            <img src="https://media.game.es/COVERV2/3D_L/172/172596.png" width="100%" alt="teclado">
            <div class="contenido">
                <span>
                    Producto <br>
                    Review del Producto
                    <br>
                </span>
                <a href="#"> comprar</a>
            </div>
        </figure>
</div>
```